# The else condition is not getting covered via test coverage

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am testing the else condition when data is empty. I am referring to else of if (data). I have checked when there is no data, the value of   console.log('xxx', data); is length 0. I have used the empty library as well {} as return observable  to simulate the service returning an empty observable.
The test does not pass as says Expected Object({  }) to be undefined.

Following are the things that i have been trying so far. Not sure where i am going wrong

```
 //component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result.length).toBe(0));
    //component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result.length).not.toBeGreaterThan(0));
    component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(1).subscribe(result => expect(result).toBe(undefined));
   // expect(component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0)).toBe(undefined);
    //expect(component.dataLength).toBe(undefined);
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem is

Component

```
 import { Observable, of, empty } from 'rxjs';

      public getOutstandingAgreements(Id: number) {
        console.log(Id);

        this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(Id).subscribe((data: AgreementsModel[]) => {
         console.log('xxx', data);
          if (data.length > 0) {
            this.myData = data;
            this.agreementData = this.myData[0].data;
            this.agreementLength = this.myData.length;
            this.calculateRemainingDaysLeft(0);
          }
        });
      }
```

Test

```
 let mockAgreementsService: Mock<AgreementsService>;
         const agreementModel : AgreementsModel[] = [{ userAgreementId: 1,
            agreementId: 1,
            code: '',
            userAgreementStateId: 1,
            userAgreementStateName: '',
            acceptanceWindowExpiry: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000) ,
            version: '',
            data: '<h1></h1>',
            authoredById: 1,
            authoredByName: '',
            authored: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)  ,
            issuedById: 1,
            issuedByName: '',
            issued: new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 24*60*60*1000) }];


          configureTestSuite(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              imports: [SharedModule, FontAwesomeModule],
              declarations: [AgreementComponent, CustomScrollDirective],
              providers: [{ provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
              { provide: AgreementsService, useFactory: () => mockAgreementsService.Object   }]
            });
          });

          function setupComponent() {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AgreementComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;

          }


          beforeEach(() => {
            mockAgreementsService = new Mock<AgreementsService>({
              getOutstandingAgreements: () => of(agreementModel),
              updateAgreement: () => Promise.resolve([])
            });
            });




           fit('should not return data when  getOutstandingAgreements is called', () => {
setupComponent();
mockAgreementsService.extend({ getOutstandingAgreements: () => of(<AgreementsModel[]>{})});
//component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result.length).toBe(0));
//component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result.length).not.toBeGreaterThan(0));
component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(1).subscribe(result => expect(result).toBe(undefined));
// expect(component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0)).toBe(undefined);
//expect(component.dataLength).toBe(undefined);
```

});

**Update 1**

The following passes the tests however the test coverage fails saying else condition not met.

```
mockAgreementsService.extend({ getOutstandingAgreements: () => of<AgreementsModel[]>([]) });
component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result.length).not.toBeGreaterThan(0));
```

Comment: Your mock should return undefined. The if check returns true with an empty array []

Comment: I have tried the following but test still does not cover.   it('should not return data when  getOutstandingAgreements is called', () => {
    setupComponent();
    mockAgreementsService.extend({ getOutstandingAgreements: () => undefined});
    //component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0).subscribe(result => expect(result).toBe(undefined));
    expect(component.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(0)).toBe(undefined);
  });

Comment: I have just updated the post . Please see the update section. The test passes however test coverage fails

Comment: Can you share a fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subscribing to the observable so it's not going inside of the subscription inside of the getOutstandingArguments function in your test.

To test the logic inside of the subscription you need to make sure your action will trigger the subscription in the test, so in your case you want to call the method directly. You would want your test to be something like this:

```
it('should not set data when getArguments is called', () => {
    /* setup return value to be empty array */
    mockAgreementsService.extend({ getOutstandingAgreements: () => of(<AgreementsModel[]>{})});

    // after setting up the return value now call component.getOutstandingAgreements
    component.getOutstandingAgreemnts(0);

    // now check that data has not been modified
    // note I do not know what the initial value of myData is I am assuming it is an empty array
    expect(component.myData.length).toBe(0);
    /* if myData is not initialized and not set to an empty array by default do the following */
    expect(component.myData).toBe(undefined);
}
```

Now it should go inside of the subscription of the observable created inside of the method in the Component as apposed to the subscription you made in the test

Comment: I am getting error  Error: <spyOn> : getOutstandingAgreements has already been spied upon. As you can see I am using  mockAgreementsService.extend({ getOutstandingAgreements: () => of<AgreementsModel[]>([]) }); Whats wrong with that

Comment: nothing is wrong with that you can do it that way. replacing my spy with your extend should work the same way. I'm not familiar with extending that is why I typed my answer out the way I did

Comment: I am now getting error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: change the expect to (component.myData).toBe(undefined); I wasn't sure how you myData was defined I assumed it was an empty array